# "The project's targets cannot be changed. The selected targets require the project to opt-into NuGet 3.0 support"

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I'm unable to add one project as a reference to another project because they target different platforms.

However, when I try to change the platform targets in my Xamarin Forms app, I get the following error

> The project's targets cannot be changed. The selected targets require the project to opt-into NuGet 3.0 support, however, Visual Studio cannot automatically do this for you. Please uninstall all NuGet packages and try again.

How exactly do I "opt-into Nuget 3.0 support" to fix this?  As far as I'm aware, everything is running at the latest versions.

Comment: @SushiHangover: Thanks, I didn't see that.  However, the answers there do not actually work, so it doesn't help :\

Comment: Hmmm, Do you have any referenced Windows 8/8.1 (phone or not) projects in your solution?

Comment: @SushiHangover I ended up having to completely remove _all_ dependencies and reinstall all of them.  It took the better part of a day.  Sigh.

Comment: Are you able the diff the old and new  `.csproj` `.sln` `.config` to see actually  what is getting set by doing that? I done two solution sets that had that problem for a client actually that way but due to timing never was able to go back to review their diffs in git to see what actually has to change.